# How to find out from Selenium that requests on UI are finished

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and I have UI that does calls which have effect once user starts working with it. However I would like to know if there is a way to find out if all requests get responses - for automation purposes to wait properly for that and not to start too quickly/ or to hardcode wait.

I am thinking of using CDP but dont know if it is capable of this functionality to retrieve something like this based on given urls that were called?

Comment: You should use webdriverwaits with explicit conditions: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Comment: That by itself is not very helpful. It still will give you just explicit option to wait - but my problem is about the object you are waiting for. Most of the times you can wait for some object in DOM structure lets say. Now to requests are not affecting anything in it initially. So I need to have a way how to check if browser requests (e.g. for url endpoint /123) has finished (or has some correct status for cases like SSE calls).

Comment: Once a request has finished, a DOM update may occur.  (usually that's the case...  offhand I can't think of any time it wouldn't...)  So waiting for the request to get it's callback isn't enough.  You'll usually want to wait until the DOM has updated.

Comment: If you need to react to an event such as a notification which can happen at any time you might consider using a WebDriverListener: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverListener.html

Comment: Not very usefull in both cases. Those calls just stores temporary data to memory. So no DOM is updated. Nor its matter of notification.